# Use nested controllers in ngRoute - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have this in `main.html`:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <form ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
  <input ng-model="query" ng-change="changed(query)" />
 </form>
</div>
```

And, `index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
 <nav ng-controller="NavCtrl">
 ...
 </nav>
 <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And, my ngRoute config is as follows:

```
module.config(function($routeProvider)){
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
  controller: 'SearchCtrl'
 });
}
```

I tried accessing `$scope.$parent` in `SearchCtrl.js` looking for `$scope` of `MainCtrl` but I am getting `undefined`.

I tried changing the controller in my config but then, I am not able to access `SearchCtrl`. What should I do?

Comment: There shouldn't be a `<body>` in a route template. Also you would have 2 instances of `SearchCtrl` with code shown ... one nested inside the other

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah. So what do I do to make sure I have both controllers nested? Thanks.

Comment: show the body of your index.html to see your `ng-view`

Comment: @charlietfl added the `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on structure shown everything inside `ng-view` will be in controller set by the route config .... `SearchCtrl`.

Then inside would be `MainCtrl` and inside that another (new instance) of `SearchCtrl`

So should probably change route controller to `MainCtrl` and remove `ng-controller="MainCtrl"`

```
module.config(function($routeProvider)){
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'
 });
}
```

main.html

```
<div>
 <form ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
  <input ng-model="query" ng-change="changed(query)" />
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main.html already in SearchCtrl scope and you don't need to define the scope again in the view.

Then, defining MainCtrl inside main.html which is under "SearchCtrl" scope will not take MainCtrl as its parent.

Hence remove both controller from main.html

```
 <form>
 <input ng-model="query" ng-change="changed(query)" />
</form>
```

Now in index.html, put the MainCtrl as parent to ng-view

```
.......
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <div ng-view></div>
</div>
.......
```

Now try accessing $scope.$parent in your SearchCtrl then you could see it.

Comment: But what if I want `MainCtrl` only for this particular view? Thanks!